# compare values in an array to a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a program that determines if a number is between two values in an array.

Here is an example of the array I am using.

```
var attackArray = new Array (2);
attackArray[0] = new Array("0","1","2","2","2","3","4");
attackArray[1] = new Array("2","3","2","3","2","3","4");
```

I am using the following code to compare the number against the first two values in the array.  I then loop through the array until I find a line that meets the requirements.  The number must be >= to the first number and <= the second number.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
function leveltest ( number)
{
    var attack = attackArray.length;


    for ( var count = 0 ; count < attack; count ++)
   {
      if ((number >= Number(attackArray [count][0])) && (number <= Number(attackArray [count][1])))
      {
        do something ;
      }
   }  

 }
```

If  someone can look at my code and explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Given an example of what the expected inputs/outputs are. Also, you're missing `attackArray[1]` and you're using strings when you should be using numbers.

Comment: attackArray[2] should have been attackArray[1] ?

Comment: attack = attackArray.length; will always return 2 because there are only 2 of them. Did you want to instead loop the elements in the respective arrays ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to compare a number to each range of numbers defined by the item values with the same index in element 0 and element 1 of attackArray. If that is right, then the following applies.

The problems present in your code snippet were:

1. You have the index wrong on line 3. Your third line, `attackArray[2] = new Array("1","3","2","3","2","3","4");` is creating a new third element in the attackArray created on the first line. Instead, I think you are wanting to populate the second element of attackArray which should be `attackArray[1] = new Array("1","3","2","3","2","3","4");` Or you could use different array syntax as shown below.
2. In the function, you were using the length of attackArray `var attack = attackArray.length;`, to control the `for` loop following. Instead, you will want, `var attack = attackArray[0].length;` so long as `attackArray[0]` and `attackArray[1]` are the same length. You can think of it like this, you were getting your length along the wrong dimension of your array. You were getting the length "down" your array or list of objects, ran than "across" the horizontal dim of your array.
3. In the function, you are confused on how to loop through the array, and you have this `attackArray [count][0]` and `attackArray [count][1]` backwards. Instead they should be `attackArray[0][count]` and `attackArray[1][count]`. This will allow you to properly compare your number with each item in element 0 and the item of the same index in element 1.

The following code should be a concise, correct working piece of code to accomplish your goal. You can take and plug this in to jsfiddle.net and it should work in Chrome with the Javascript console used to view the results in the log. Here it is:

```
var attackArray = [];
attackArray[0] = ["0","0","2","2","2","3","4"];
attackArray[1] = ["1","3","2","3","2","3","4"];

function leveltest (number){
  var attack = attackArray[0].length;
  for (var count = 0;count < attack;count ++){
    if ((number >= Number(attackArray [0][count])) &&
        (number <= Number(attackArray [1][count]))) {
      console.log(number + " matches at index " + count);
      }
    }  
}
leveltest(2);
```

Comment: Chad  Thanks for the help.  Your Answer is the one that helped me the most.  I was able to solve my issue.  Your explanation helped more than the code.   Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your second element in attackArray has the wrong index.

```
attackArray[2] = new Array("1","3","2","3","2","3","4");
```

attackArray.length == 2
you "count" can go up to 1, attackArray[1] is not defined by you.

Answer (score 0):

The second comparation inside the if is wrong. At the second loop it will be attackArray[1][1] and you created an attackArray[0] and attackArray[2].